# I resized with GIMP and mtPaint, it does not work. The image size does not change when I put it slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

```js
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

```css
.mySlides {display:none;}
```

```html
<body>

<h2 class="w3-center">Automatic Slideshow</h2>

<div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:600px">
  <img class="mySlides" src="cigand1.jpeg" style="width:30%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="eu1.jpeg" style="width:30%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="hun1.jpg" style="width:30%">
</div>

</body>
```

I think the code is right, but the third image is bigger in the slideshow than I want. I resized the image but does not work. 
How to solve this problem? Did you meet problem like this? Now you can not see the pictures, the problem is other.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but checking your code, you are just setting a max-width to the image.

```
<div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:600px">
```

That means, if the picture width is less than 600px, (500px for instance) it will display a 500px width picture.

You can try something like this

```
<div class="w3-content w3-section" style="width:600px">
```

But the best way to do so, is to have all the pictures with the same width.

Comment: Good! I just have to use images in the same size. Thanks a lot!